# Cron Not working on server

Tags: 14.04, cron

Cronjob is not working on server properly, when i am adding any cron like for every 1 hour or every 2 hour and after restarting cron service cronjob execute those script in every 1 minute.

And when i'm giving any exact time for executing any script it works properly.

cronjob like its for every 1 hour but it runs in every 1 minute

```
* */1 * * * python3 /var/wwwroot/script.py
```

How do i resolve this problem.

Comment: python3 is probably not in the cron's PATH, please have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2546509/2069348, and the /1 is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

For every hour, you want:

```
0 * * * * python3 /var/wwwroot/script.py
```

1. 0 = Run at '0' minutes past hour
2. * = Run every hour of the day
3. * = every day of month
4. * = every month of year
5. * = every day of week

For every 2 hours, at 30m past the hour you want:

```
30 */2 * * * python3 /var/wwwroot/script.py
```

Reference:

- https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/
- `man 5 crontab`

Comment: For every half hour or 2 hour what will be cronjob?

Comment: edited answer to incorporate

Comment: Thanks dpb, One more que: is there any recent changes in crontab syntax?

Comment: not really.  I think the most recent are the aliases. that let you type out things like `@hourly /run/this/script`, but again, see `man 5 crontab` for more info